# como generar una secuencia varchar en sql server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image]

quiero hacer que esta columna ID que es un campo varchar se me genere automáticamente, cuando inserto el nombre, como si fuera una secuencia, ayuda

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, pero de todas maneras, la habilidad de crear secuencias no existe en SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @sstan exacto, y tampoco existen en SQL Server 2008 R2 (aka SQL Server 2010). Empezaron en SQL Server 2012

Comment: @sstan tengo sql server 2014 instalado como lo puedo hacer entonces?

Comment: @Frankenstainero entonces por qué etiquetaste la pregunta con SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: ... y adicionalmente, vas a tener que aclarar la pregunta. No entiendo qué quieres decir con *quiero que la secuencia me vaya incrementando con dos caracteres de manera secuencia*. Tal vez ayudaría que des ejemplos concretos de lo que buscas.

Comment: Aún no entiendo la pregunta, pero suena como que puedes crear una secuencia y una columna calculada en base a esa secuencia

Comment: Exacto una columna como si fuera un campo autoincrementable pero ca a tener 2 caracteres mas el incremento

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una secuencia solo puede generar valores numéricos, no valores con caracteres formateados como buscas (ejemplo: `CUS00001`).  De modo que, aunque pudieras usar una secuencia, te tocaría a ti usar el valor que te devuelve y aplicarle el formato deseado.

Como se comentó debajo de tu pregunta, una manera que parecería conveniente a lo que deseas hacer es mediante una columna calculada. Pero tristemente, SQL Server no parece permitir el uso de secuencias en la definición de una columna calculada.

Probablemente, la opción mas sencilla en tu caso es, en vez de usar una secuencia, que bases la columna calculada en otra columna `IDENTITY`:

```
create table tbl (
  Id int identity not null,
  CusId as 'CUS' + format(Id, '00000'),
  -- ...
)
```

Por supuesto, esto implica agregar una columna adicional `IDENTITY` para mantener el valor numérico.  De lo contrario, tendrías que explorar una solución usando un trigger para poner al día la columna usando una secuencia, pero esto tendría otros inconvenientes.

Comment: Pero creo que la secuencia es para eso para poder crearlas sin que necesariamente sean  un numero

Comment: Aunque es cierto que puedes ajustar el tipo deseado, la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) es clara de que una secuencia solo puede basarse en un tipo numérico. Cita: *Una secuencia se puede definir como de cualquier tipo __entero__*

Comment: se que se puede, porque estaba buscando informacacion y la informacion resulto correcto lo que quiero es que ejemplo tengo dos columna nombre y codigo quiero que si inserto el nombre me genere el codigo de manera secuencial, sin tener que insertarlo como si fuera una propiedad IDENTITY

Comment: Si estás convencido que es posible hacerlo con una secuencia, ¿porque no compartes la información que encontrastes al respecto? Y cuidado que no te hayas fijado en información que era para MySQL, porque allí sí es posible definir una columna formateada con secuencia automática.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql este es el link

Comment: ¿Cual parte de ese link te dio la impresión que podías generar una columna alfanumérica usando una secuencia? Revisando la versión en español del [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql), me parece que las 2 citas siguientes son bien claras: 1) *Devuelve un __número__ utilizando el tipo de la secuencia.* y 2) *El `NEXT VALUE FOR` función __no se puede usar__ en las situaciones siguientes: ... En vistas, en funciones definidas por el usuario o __en columnas calculadas__*.

Comment: gracias por la información seguiré intentándolo como pueda, gracias por la aclaración